# how to access multiple class of child tags and the child tags themselves of a parent element in html using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I am creating a page where the user checks the checkbox of the dish name and set the quantity of orders they want for that particular dish. I want to give it a logic where it increments the quantity of a dish only when that particular dish is checked.
To do this all I can think of is to use the child elements of the ul element in the form section. I want to write a function in js that first checks if the checkbox of a particular li element is checked or not. If checked then only will it increase the quantity on the button pressed. But I can't figure out how to do so.
This is my HTML code.

```
<form>
                <ul id = 'food_tracker'>

                    <li class="item-block">
                        <div class="food_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="Food-item" id="food-item-" value="Tandoori Chicken"/>
                            <label for="food-item-one">Tandoori Chicken</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span class="decrease">-</span>
                            <p id="value">1</p>
                            <span class="increase">+</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing">
                            <p>$150</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li class="item-block">
                        <div class="food_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="Food-item" id="food-item-two" value="Schezwan Chicken"/>
                            <label for="food-item-two">Schezwan Chicken</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span class="decrease">-</span>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <span class="increase">+</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing">
                            <p>$329</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li class="item-block">
                        <div class="food_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="Food-item" id="food-item-three" value="Chicken Lollypop"/>
                            <label for="food-item-three"> Chicken Lollypop</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span class="decrease">-</span>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <span class="increase">+</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing">
                            <p>$229</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li class="item-block">
                        <div class="food_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="Food-item" id="food-item-four" value="Russian Chicken"/>
                            <label for="food-item-four">Russian Chicken</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span class="decrease">-</span>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <span class="increase">+</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing">
                            <p>$157</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
    
                    <li class="item-block">
                        <div class="food_box">
                            <input type="checkbox" class="cb" name="Food-item" id="food-item-five" value="Afghani Chicken"/>
                            <label for="food-item-five">Afghani Chicken</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="quantity">
                            <span class="decrease">-</span>
                            <p>1</p>
                            <span class="increase">+</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="pricing">
                            <p value="149">$149</p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
 </form
```

In the javascript section, I am trying to use conditionals that if the checkbox of a particular element is checked only then can the quantity increase or decrease.

This is the link to the page

[Online_Order_Page](https://codepen.io/antuq/pen/YzeOYPx)

Please correct me on where and what am I doing wrong.

I also want to create a function which will increase/decrease the pricing as the quantity for that particular dish increases/decreases.
Some tips on this will be appreciated as well.

Comment: I would not advise to go that way. The checkbox is just a nuance to the user. Just set the initial quantity to zero and let the user freely increment those counters.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of things:

1. At the end of the js code, you loop through the items, and only attach an event listener to the buttons, if they are checked (by default, none of them are checked, so no event listeners are registered).
2. You try to attach an eventlistener to the increment/decrement buttons, but that's a NodeList of the buttons, not a single button.
3. You only have 1 `count` variable, and all the buttons are changing it. You need to keep count of each individual item's count.

A tip: Try to store your data in a different data structure. For example in an array of objects:

```js
let items = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Tandoori Chicken',
        count: 1
        checked: false,
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Schezwan Chicken',
        count: 1
        checked: false,
    },
...
];
```

You don't have to hard code them one-by-one, you can loop through the html items, get the names, the ids and the count and checked are always 1 and false by default.
While looping through them, you can attach an event listener to the checkbox, that sets the object's `checked` attribute to `true/false`, and the increment/decrement changes the count of the given object.
You will also be able to replace the shown amount within the event listener.

Comment: Your answer is a bit confusing for me. Can you simplify it for me? I am new to web development and javascript.